# Button disabled is not working in Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

I am new to angular 6 ,Here I have formControl instead of using FormGroup as per the business needs.

app.component.html

```
<button
  class="col-sm-12"
  [disabled]="comittee_Member_Name.invalid && comittee_Member_Number.invalid && comittee_Type.invalid &&  comittee_Member_Position.invalid && comittee_Member_Status.invalid"
>
  Save
</button>
```

Here I want to disable the button if **anyone** of the formControl is invalid. But in my case it validates the first formcontrol (comittee_Member_Name )only.

app.component.ts

```
comittee_Member_Name =new FormControl();
  comittee_Member_Number = new FormControl();
  comittee_Type = new FormControl();
  comittee_Member_Position = new FormControl();
  comittee_Member_Status = new FormControl();
```

Can anyone help me to solve this .

Comment: Try replacing `&&` with `||` in the condition.

Comment: I think these all should be enclosed in a formGroup because formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive

Comment: I would try to display the value of each of the controls `invalid` state on screen to make sure they contain the values you expect. It sounds like `ConnorsFan` suggestion of `||` is what you want.

Comment: @ConnorsFan it's worked thanks

Comment: It seems it will only be disabled if all your conditions satisfy. Replace it with || operator and check

Answer (score 5):

Prove this:

```
<button class="col-sm-12" [disabled]="comittee_Member_Name.$invalid || comittee_Member_Number.$invalid || comittee_Type.$invalid ||  comittee_Member_Position.$invalid || comittee_Member_Status.$invalid" >Save</button>
```

**You have used the logical operator incorrectly.**

**&&:**
Called Logical **AND** operator. If both operands are true, then the condition becomes true.

**||:**
Called Logical **OR** Operator. If any of the operands are true, then the condition becomes true.